# JavaScript onload function call suddenly produces "Object expected"

Tags: javascript, sorttable.js

The following onload function call was working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">   
    function frameloaded() {  
       if (parent.leftframe) {  
          parent.leftframe.reportRightFrameReloaded();  
       }  
    }  
    </script>      
    </head>    
    <body onload="frameloaded();">  
 .... etc.
```

until I added an external javascript reference

```
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sorttable.js"></script<
```

immediately before it. Then suddenly it started giving me "Object expected" in IE (I have IE8) and simply stopped working in Firefox (3.6.3). I figured there was a duplicate function name in the included file, so I gave it a random name and it still failed. I tried using

```
    onload="this.frameloaded();"
```

and

```
    onload="document.frameloaded();"
```

with no luck.
I tried moving my function above the included statement, but just got an empty frame.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: When you use the IE8 debugger, at what line does that error occur?

Comment: are you sure there isn't an error in `sorttable.js`?

Comment: In Firefox, you can use the Error Console to look for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should keep your html in .html files, css in .css files and JavaScript in .js files. You can use `document.onload = function(e){};` to set the `onload` event, but pretty soon you're going to want more out of javascript, which is when you'll probably start using a JS framework like jQuery so that you can attach multiple event handlers and do things a lot easier. For now though, avoid putting JavaScript in HTML attributes whenever possible.

Comment: @Hamish: It is quite possible that something in sorttable.js is causing the problem. But it is such a magical piece of code (I downloaded it free from http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) that I hate to cast any doubt on it. However, since reading your comment I have found a bug page for it and I will research further there. The magic is that once you have included sorttable.js, you just have to add the attribute class="sortable" to any html <table> element and the user can sort any column with a simple mouse-click on the column header!

Comment: @Pointy: I am not familiar with the IE8 debugger. I will look into using it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

@Hamish was right. The problem was in sorttable.js. It uses window.onload, which conflicted with my BODY onload. In sorttable.js, there were several window.onload statements within some elaborate logic, so I couldn't just use the recommended solution in such cases, which would be to trigger all the required onload  functions in the BODY onload event.

Instead, my solution, which I am not entirely comfortable with, is to put the contents of my frameloaded() method at the bottom of the BODY, but not inside a function. This way it executes as late as possible during the load process. This works (i.e. it runs after the tables that have to be loaded first have been loaded) in IE and Safari, but I am having trouble with the other browsers.